# Cobb - Douglas Production Function

Tags: econometrics

let's say that we have complete data on the sample of companies about their capital (K), labor (L) and materials used in the production (M) and the total output of each company.

Let's have Cobb-Douglas specification: $$Y_{it} = A_{it}K_{it}^{a}L_{it}^{b}M_{it}^{c}$$.
In the text that I am reading, that we can calculate A (Total Factor Productivity) as the residual of the Cobb-Douglas production function.

But I have no idea of how do we construct Cobb-Douglas production function? Can anyone help me on this?

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure to understand your question. But as far as I understand it.
If you have a dataset with $Y,K,L,M$ over a set of corporates over some years, you can estimate $A$ using a log-log regression, since the following model is compatible with your Coob-Douglas specification:
$$\log Y=a \log K + b \log L + c \log M + \log A.$$
It is clearly the specification of a linear regression where $\log A$ is the residual.

To be more accurate, using script letters for the log of capital ones:

- $d\mu(y,k,l,m)$ is the joint repartition of the log of the activity of the firms in your database;
- minimize $\int_{(y,k,l,m)}|| a k + b l + c m - y|| d\mu(y,k,l,m)$ over $(a,b,c)$;
- observe the residuals of the upper regression $\epsilon$, compute its std $\sigma$,
- if you go back to exponentials, you obtain:
  $$Y=K^a L^b M^c \mathbb{E}\exp(\epsilon).$$
- note $\mathbb{E}\exp(\epsilon)=\sigma^2/2$; it is your estimate for $A$.